# how to make a django model with no id column and primary key?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, primary-key

i am working with big data and i can have an extra column like id. i cant put the primary key to any other single column, because of duplicate. and even more i cant have primary key on two column or more because my data is not unique. so the only way to get rid of the id column with a primary key left for me is to stop django making it!
and i don't know how...
i tried to edit the operation part of the migration file before doing the migrate command but it didn't work.
even if i delete the id column in the migration file it still make it /:(.

Comment: "i cant put the primary key to any other single column, because of duplicate. and even more i cant have primary key on two column or more because my data is not unique"? It's unclear what you mean. Can you explain it little bit clearly.

Comment: Primary key is a must, auto or custom as I understand.

Comment: i know but i have been told that i can add a new migration file and then put the sql command in the operation part of it that drops the column with the primary key.
my friends was ok doing it. but i can't. i don't know why it doesn't work.